# pass paramter in sequence

Tags: ios, swift, web-services

when I calling webservice i pass parameter as below

```
["user_auth": dicAuth,"application":"","name_value_list":"","user_details":dicUserDetail,"language":"en_us"]
```

but when I call webservice it change sequence as below

```
 ["application": "", "language": "en_us", "user_auth": ["password": "admin", "user_name": "admin"], "user_details": ["device_token_type": "1235145s4df2315423123454231", "device_type": "iOS"], "name_value_list": ""]
```

but I want to pass in sequence. any help?

Comment: Dictionary has no sorting criteria , also does this make sense the backend will be able to read it anyway

Comment: no its not working it required in sequence

Comment: @Sh_Khan is correct - the sequence shouldn't matter to the backend. If it _does_, then you need to use and Array rather than a Dictionary.

Comment: @Sh_Khan will you please give me example

Comment: How are you calling the *webservice*?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found solution with below third party

https://github.com/lukaskubanek/OrderedDictionary